# After login, it display 'Unfortunately, app has stop'

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I tried to run my login page and suddenly it displays 'Unfortunately app has stop'. Here is my entire logcat stack trace. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
10-16 11:10:08.946 7285-7285/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
10-16 11:10:09.022 7285-7285/? W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
10-16 11:10:09.028 7285-7285/? W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
10-16 11:10:09.036 7285-7285/? W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
10-16 11:10:09.762 7285-7358/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
10-16 11:10:09.822 7285-7285/? I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
10-16 11:10:09.835 7285-7285/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-16 11:10:09.912 7285-7376/? W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
10-16 11:10:09.940 7285-7376/? I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
10-16 11:10:10.086 7285-7285/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-16 11:10:10.104 7285-7285/? W/ResourceType: Found multiple library tables, ignoring...
10-16 11:10:10.420 7285-7285/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
10-16 11:10:10.421 7285-7285/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$2>
10-16 11:10:10.804 7285-7426/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Render dirty regions requested: true
10-16 11:10:10.818 7285-7285/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-16 11:10:11.005 7285-7426/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013_msm8226_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
    Build Date: 01/21/15 Wed
    Local Branch: 
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.7
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.013 +  NOTHING
10-16 11:10:11.023 7285-7426/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-16 11:10:11.120 7285-7426/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-16 11:10:11.262 7285-7285/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-16 11:10:11.311 7285-7285/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1008e773 time:150860796
10-16 11:10:24.417 7285-7285/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1008e773 time:150873902
10-16 11:10:44.937 7285-7285/? I/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzao@19f2a066
10-16 11:10:46.382 7285-7307/? D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying id token listeners about user ( rX50zjEENoQeeUirMV8kn2ARtEk2 ).
10-16 11:10:46.435 7285-7285/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:net.ji.hicadmin time:150895920
10-16 11:10:46.976 7285-7285/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
10-16 11:10:46.977 7285-7285/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
10-16 11:10:47.045 7285-8791/? I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3>
10-16 11:10:47.049 7285-8791/? E/RunLoop: Uncaught exception in Firebase Database runloop (3.0.0). Please report to firebase-database-client@google.com
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider$3
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider.produceIdTokenListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:85)
        at com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider.addTokenChangeListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:80)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.deferredInitialization(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:109)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.access$000(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:55)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:94)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-16 11:10:47.090 7285-7285/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-16 11:10:47.096 7285-7285/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.ji.hicadmin, PID: 7285
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.ji.hicadmin/net.ji.hicadmin.ListActivity}: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@17d1d313 rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@2658d950[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@17d1d313 rejected from com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop$1@2658d950[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2011)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:793)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:503)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:592)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.DefaultRunLoop.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:105)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.Repo.scheduleNow(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:276)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addEventRegistration(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:233)
        at com.google.firebase.database.Query.addValueEventListener(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.4:149)
        at net.ji.hicadmin.ListActivity.onCreate(ListActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736) 
10-16 11:10:52.551 7285-7299/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the log you got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.database.android.AndroidAuthTokenProvider` it seems like you miss something in adding Firebase into your project. First please follow the exact steps in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app).

- Make sure to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the very bottom of your app module level file
- Add app module level dependencies (change versions
  according to Firebase versions you're using)

  ```
  // Firebase Realtime database
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'

  // Firebase storage
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1'

  // Firebase authentication
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'

  // FirebaseUI authentication
  implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'

  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
  ```
- Add Google Services plugin in project level dependency

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          google()
          jcenter()
      }

      dependencies {

          // For Firebase -- Google Services plugin
          classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'  // Google Services plugin
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for response. I just solved it by upgrading firebase database library to the latest version.

Comment: welcome .. just be cautious for firebase upgrades as they get some functionalities deprecated over time .. happy coding :)